# How to create a http interceptor to return an error within 'response'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic angular `http` interceptor to handle all my errors. I require to check if the returned `data` is every a typeof `string`, to handle this as an error, not a success.

```
'response': function(response) {
    if(typeof response.data === 'string') {
        response.status = 422;
        return $q.reject(response);
    } else {
        return response;
    }
},
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

At the moment, if the `data` is a typeof `string`, it will enter the correct if statement, change the status, and return. Although, Angular is not seeing this as an error. Within my `http` function, it calls neither success or error callbacks. If the API returns a legit error, it goes into 'responseError' successfully, and calls the error callback like expected.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "http://mydomain/api/login",
  data: $.param({
     username: "test",
     password: "test"
  }),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(successCallback(response), errorCallback(response));
```

How can I get my interceptor to return an error that Angular can recognise to enter the error callback from my `http` function?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you need to make a factory for common ajaz response and responseError as below and inject it in system's configuration as below.

// Angular factory in seperate file and load in your index.

```
angular.module('yourApp').factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, $location) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
            // do something on success
            if(typeof response.data === 'string') {
                response.status = 422;
                return $q.reject(response);
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        },

        // optional method
       'responseError': function(rejection) {
          // do something on error
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Now intercept in config in your app.js

```
.config([ '$httpProvider', 
    function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
} ])
```

This works for me.